# $stateProvider won't route with $urlRouterProvider.otherwise

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

It was working before when "/" was "/main", It was able to load main and dashboard as  `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main/dashboard");`

but now I have changed to "/" instead of "/main", it doesn't work, it loads only main and not dashboard. I have changed the code because I am using [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js), and it was having an issue of looping.

following is the code sample (config.js)

```
    myapp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$compileProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $compileProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider) {


    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider

    // Main content
    .state('main', {
      abstract: false,
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "/app/views/common/content.html"
    })
    .state('main.dashboard', {
      url: "dashboard",
      templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard.html",
      requireADLogin: true,
      data: {
        pageTitle: 'Dashboard'
      }
    })
    .state('main.usermanagement', {
      url: "/usermanagement",
      template: "<div ui-view></div>",
      requireADLogin: true
    }); 

 }])
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code has resolve my issue, if anyone faces this issue when using 
 [Active Directory Authentication Library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js):

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
    var $state = $injector.get("$state");
    $state.go("main.dashboard");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this default childState for main:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/dashboard');
```

And you should write url starting with '/'

```
 .state('main.dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard.html",
    requireADLogin: true,
    data: {
    pageTitle: 'Dashboard'
 }
})
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to navigate as "/main/dashboard", in existing structure as "/dashboard" because "/" is main

Comment: You need to have in your main state view, meaning content.html <ui-view></ui-view> so that angular injects the dashboard state in it. Do you have it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you did't define URL in correct way

please use below like, url should be start with `/`

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dasenter code herehboard");`

```
$stateProvider  
.state('main', {
  abstract: false,
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "/app/views/common/content.html"
})
.state('main.dashboard', {
  url: "/dashboard",  // you missed slash `/` here
  templateUrl: "/app/views/dashboard.html",
  requireADLogin: true,
  data: {
    pageTitle: 'Dashboard'
  }
})
```

try it

Comment: Yes, I missed because , it was showing  //dashboard

Comment: Probably you missed something, please share your whole route file 
check this basic example of ui-route :  https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/helloworld#helloworldjs

Comment: I have added route file in question section.